# How many strings are there of four decimal digits that:

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I don't know which are decade digits (I suppose they are: 10, 20, 30, 40,....etc, but I'm not sure)

a) The same digits can't repeat twice

b) The string contains exactly 2 even digits

Comment: I think you meant to say decimal digits. These are the digits 0-9 used in the decimal number system.

Comment: @PeterForeman No It's decade digit

Comment: The question only makes sense with decimal digits.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Ok let it be decimal digits. If you know the answer can you help me?

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Please [edit] the question to show what you have attempted and show where you are stuck.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I know, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Is this six *different* problems or one?  Those conditions are contradictory so there are zero numbers that satisfy all six.  "can't repeat twice" is ambiguous; what does repeating "once" mean and how is repeating "twice" different.

Comment: "but I don't know how to solve this problem"  But you *MUST* have some *THOUGHTS*!  I mean what about "exactly four $9$s"?  What does that mean?  I mean you can at least think about counting all of them.  Or counting the counter examples.  I'm sorry, but I can not accept that any four year old with no math education at all can be excused from not having thoughts about how to maybe do this.  The may be ill formed and incomplete and the may be dead wrong but *everyone* can think of *something*.

Comment: @fleablood All questions are different from each other

Comment: @fleablood I thought it was a question about decade digits and I didn't know which numbers are they, so I came here to ask about this and to see your solutions about this. I have examples but different from this. But anyway thank you for your respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all straightforward applications of the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) which paraphrased says something like this:

> To count the number of outcomes or arrangements in a scenario, if you can perfectly describe each such outcome via a sequence of steps such that the *number* of options at each step does not depend on any previously made selections (*though which options are available may change*) and every outcome is achieved by exactly one unique sequence of selections, then the total number of outcomes is the product of the number of choices for each step.

I will solve two for you, part (a) and part (b) and leave the rest for you to do.

---

Part (a) asks us to find the number of strings of length $4$ using digits such that no digit is repeated.  To do this, we approach via rule of product by describing the sequence of steps and noting the number of options available for each step.

- Choose the first digit (10 options)
- Choose the second digit (9 options)
- Choose the third digit (8 options)
- Choose the fourth digit (7 options)

The total is then the product of these, $10\times 9\times 8\times 7$.

Note, depending on what was chosen for the first digit, the available options for the second digit will change so as to not include what was used for the first.  The *number* of options however will always be nine regardless which exact choice was made for the first digit.

Note also, we could have specified these steps in a different order, for example by choosing the digits in reverse order by starting with the fourth digit, or any number of other ways.  There will often be many different equally correct approaches to a problem which may even lead to different expressions for the final result.  Assuming everything was done correctly for both approaches, despite the expressions looking different this would imply that the expressions are in fact equal and is a useful tool for proving identities in combinatorics.

---

Part (b) asks us to have the string contain exactly two even digits.

- Pick the locations used by the even digits ($\binom{4}{2}=6$ options)
- Pick which digit is used in the left-most space designated for even digits ($5$ options)
- Pick which digit is used for the remaining even digit ($5$ options)
- Pick which digit is used for the left-most space designated for odd digits ($5$ options)
- Pick which digit is used for the remaining space ($5$ options)

Multiplying these gives us a total of $\binom{4}{2}\times 5\times 5\times 5\times 5$ total outcomes.

Note, $\binom{n}{r}$ is the notation used for the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and is a common counting tool that you should become intimately familiar with.

Comment: Thank you so much :)